# Cannot find module 'Parse' in Heroku using node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-platform

I am using nodejs to access [Parse](http://parse.com). It works fine locally. But when I push the code to Heroku, I get the error as below:

```
6T13:34:58+00:00 app[worker.1]:

2013-03-16T13:34:58+00:00 app[worker.1]: module.js:340

2013-03-16T13:34:58+00:00 app[worker.1]: throw err;

2013-03-16T13:34:58+00:00 app[worker.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)

2013-03-16T13:34:58+00:00 app[worker.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)

2013-03-16T13:34:58+00:00 app[worker.1]: at Module.require (module.js:364:17)

2013-03-16T13:34:58+00:00 app[worker.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

2013-03-16T13:34:58+00:00 app[worker.1]: **Error: Cannot find module 'Parse'**

2013-03-16T13:34:58+00:00 app[worker.1]: ^

2013-03-16T13:34:58+00:00 app[worker.1]: at require (module.js:380:17)

2013-03-16T13:34:58+00:00 app[worker.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:2:10)

2013-03-16T13:34:58+00:00 app[worker.1]: at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

2013-03-16T13:34:58+00:00 app[worker.1]: at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

2013-03-16T13:34:58+00:00 app[worker.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

2013-03-16T13:34:58+00:00 app[worker.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

2013-03-16T13:34:59+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 8

2013-03-16T13:34:59+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

But I can run my code by using "foreman start" which is the heroku simulator.

As @PeterLyons request. The Profile file as below:

```
worker: node server.js
```

The package.json

```
{
"name": "app name",
"description": "app description",
"version": "1.0.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "cron": ">=1.0.1",
    "jsdom" : ">=0.5.2", 
    "parse" : "*"
    }
}
```

When I pushed the code to heroku, I can see it fetched the **parse** dependence for me correctly.

```
   parse@1.2.2 /tmp/build_3jl0a1qf6bwt3/node_modules/parse
   localStorage@1.0.2 /tmp/build_3jl0a1qf6bwt3/node_modules/parse/node_modules/localStorage
   xmlhttprequest@1.5.0 /tmp/build_3jl0a1qf6bwt3/node_modules/parse/node_modules/xmlhttprequest
   Dependencies installed
-----> Building runtime environment
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> worker
```

I don't know why there is an error in runtime.

Thanks

Comment: post your `package.json` and `Procfile` please. 1st guess is your package.json file doesn't correctly list the `parse` module as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks Peter Lyons, I have updated my original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your .js file, use `require('parse')` with a lowercase "p". JavaScript and node.js package names are case sensitive.

Comment: Great. I thought OSX is case sensitive.

Comment: The OSX HFS filesystem is case-insensitive by default, but Heroku dynos are linux and use case-sensitive filesystems. In any case, the node convention is case sensitive module and package names, so always require modules using matching case and you won't have any issues.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep an eye on this later.

Answer (score 2):

`2013-03-16T13:34:58+00:00 app[worker.1]: **Error: Cannot find module 'Parse'**`

Make sure that module is part of your `package.json`.

Comment: Yes, it is in my package.json. I can run app locally, and use "foreman start" as well.